# Converting a dynamic page to a static page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project in which I need to take a dynamic website like adobe spark - https://spark.adobe.com/gallery/gallery-editors-choice/example/maggie-to-monte/ and create a static html+css page out of it. Later this page will be converted into a pdf.

As I understand , the interactivity is mainly supported through Javascript which manipulate CSS+HTML . I want to know if there is a way to find all the states of the DOM of a given web page. As in it may require to simulate various events in the webpage and then capturing the state DOM after each event.Is there already any way to do it?

Is the problem of writing a program to record all the states of a program is even possible ?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score -2):

You may try a software wkhtmltopdf available for both linux and windows.
You may also try htmldoc

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!